# Successive outcome probability problem

Tags: probability, statistics

Here is another question from the book of V. Rohatgi and A. Saleh. I would like to ask help again. Here it goes:

A biased coin with probability $p$, $0 < p < 1$, of success (heads) is tossed until for the first time, the same result occurs three times in succession (that is, three heads or three tails in succession). Find the probability that the game will end at the seventh throw.

So here is what I have so far. I considered two cases: (1) _ _ _ THHH ; and (2) _ _ _ HTTT. So for the first case, the only ways that the 3 blanks can be filled up are through the outcomes $$\text{HHT, HTH, THH, TTH, and THT}$$ So what I did is that I took the individual probabilities of each sequence, e.g. $$\text{P{HHT}}=p^2(1-p)$$ and so on. So I add all these 5 probabilities and multiplied the sum with having THHH as the last 4 outcomes, i.e. $$\text{P{THHH}}=p^3(1-p)$$ I did the same thing for the second case. Afterwards, I added probabilities for both cases; thus, giving me the result $$(1-p)p^3[1-p(1-p)^2-(1-p)^3-p^3]+p(1-p)^3[1-p^2(1-p)-p^3-(1-p)^3]$$ I would like to ask if I am doing it correctly or not, or whether there is a shorter solution. I read some texts that considered the problem as a renewal process; however, I have trouble understanding it, especially all I have found so far concern with "expected number of tosses". The answer, by the way, as given in the text is $$p^2(1-p)^2[3-7p(1-p)]$$ Can anyone verify and explain why please? Thanks

Comment: Your approach is fine.  You can take the difference of the two expressions in Alpha to see if they are in fact equal.  I didn't check the algebra.  The fact that your two terms are related by the substitution $p \to (1-p)$ supports your calculation, as the strings in $(2)$ are just the complement of the strings in $(1)$